# A basic operation of python's dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
encoder.load_state_dict({k:v for k,v in encoder_dict.items() if k in model_dict})
```

This syntax is an operation of the dictionary, but I can't understand that what does "k:v" acts?

Comment: That's a dictionary comprehension. It's creating a new dictionary from the loop.

Comment: `k:v` means `k` is the key and `v` is the value of the new dictionary element.

Comment: Dictionaries are always ```key : value``` pairs. So ```k:v``` pairs the items. ```k``` is the key and ```v``` is the item

Answer (score 2):

```
encoder.load_state_dict({k:v for k,v in encoder_dict.items() if k in model_dict})
```

This is dictionary comprehension. An equivalent code in simple terms would be:

```
new_dict = dict()
for k,v in encoder_dict.items():
    if k in model_dict:
        new_dict[k] = v
encoder.load_state_dict(new_dict)
```

where `k` and `v` corresponds to the `key` and `value` pair returned by  `encoder_dict.items()`